# How is the MobileNet preprocess input in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, python-imaging-library, mobilenet

When we use some famous CNN deep neural networks such as MobileNet, it is recommended to preprocess an image before feeding it into the network. I found a sample code that uses MobileNet. In this code, the preprocess on the image is done by the following code in TensorFlow 2.7.0:

```
tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(image)
```

I need to preprocess the input image only using PIL and OpenCV in python. Therefore, I need to know the procedure of MobileNet preprocesses in TensorFlow. I will be grateful to guide.

Comment: Why won't you check the source code for that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to read the source code. There are other operations which I should find out what are they doing exactly.

Comment: Yes, the answer is helpful for me. I also check the source code and find out it simply does the following procedure: `image_array = (image_array_1 / 127.5) - 1`. @AloneTogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/):

> [...] mobilenet.preprocess_input will scale input pixels between -1 and 1.

As already mentioned, you could also check out the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L101) itself. With `opencv`, you would just use `cv2.resize(*)` and `cv2.normalize(*)`.

Comment: cv.resize is for resampling images "spatially", i.e. "change the resolution". that may be needed to fit the input shape of the network, but it won't scale pixel *values*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The TensorFlow and Keras are use PIL instead of OpenCV. I test and find out PIL and OpenCV have little difference when reading an image. Therefore, I think I should use the normalization in PIL.